# Masking the log data in Apache2 logs

Tags: apache, logging, apache2, masking

I'm trying to mask the data in the logs of my Apache2 webserver, suppose I have page where it has query parameters called keyword which has a 16 digit random number which is no sensitive data, it's just a random number.

Let's say URL is [www.mydomain.com/?someparam=1234567890123456](http://www.mydomain.com/?someparam=1234567890123456)

Now How do I proceed to mask "1234567890123456" this kind of value in the logs in Apache2

I tired with the CustomLog method where you call /bin/sed for substitution, but that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Piped logging, like you said you tried is probably the best solution. It allows you to do any conversion you like in any programming language.

An alternative is to no longer log the request URL (nor query string ) directly, instead:

0. remove %r from your LogFormat
1. Use a custom format with %U for the path
2. Use SetEnvIf to obfuscate the query w/ a regex and substitutionb and place the result in an environment variable
3. Log the environment string directly, e.g. %U?%{my-obfuscated-query}e